# Page stored using Cloudflare Cache API expires earlier than expected

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am developing a backend API using Cloudflare Workers to cache the tokens into respective individual pages, something like [http://cache.api/[tokenId]](http://cache.api/%5BtokenId%5D) with token value itself as body content, using Cache API.

```
        const tokenId = 'fakeJWT';

        const internalUrl = ''.concat(
          'http://cache.api/',
          tokenId // the query string
        );

        const cacheUrl = new URL(internalUrl);
        const cacheKey = new Request(cacheUrl.toString());
        const cache = caches.default;

        let response = new Response(tokenId);
        response.headers.append('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=86400'); // 24 hours

        await cache.put(cacheKey, response.clone());
```

I've configured `Cache-Control` header with 24 hours expiry. Then, I wrote another API in the same Cloudflare Workers to check the existence of the cache, it exists after 10 minutes but does not exist after 15 minutes.

```
        const internalUrl = ''.concat(
            'http://cache.api/',
            tokenId // the query string
        );

        const cacheUrl = new URL(internalUrl);
        const cacheKey = new Request(cacheUrl.toString());
        const cache = caches.default;

        let response = await cache.match(cacheKey);
        if (!response) {
            console.log(
              `Cache url for ${cacheUrl} is not present`
            );

            return unauthorised(`${pathName}: This user session has expired! cache url is ${cacheUrl}`);
        }
        else
        {
            let response = new Response(tokenId);
            response.headers.append('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=86400'); // in seconds
    
            await cache.put(cacheKey, response.clone());
        }
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may be happening is a cache `miss` rather than an expiration. When using Cloudflare for caching, you shouldn't expect caching to be guaranteed, in particular using the cache API the docs mention it being data-center specific (not propagated globally) -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/cache/#background

Caching should be mechanism for improving performance, but not relied upon for guaranteed storage in other words. If your use-case requires this, it would be better to use the Workers Key Value -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/how-kv-works/

Comment: If you enable [Tiered Caching](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/tiered-cache/), then the cache is no longer data-center specific. All Cloudflare data centers would use a centralized cache for your site. This greatly reduces the number of cache misses.

Comment: I'd be curious how Tiered Caching works when the request is not to an "origin server" on your account though? In the case of using a worker / cache API. The documentation doesn't seem to cover that.